# Providing TypeScript definitions for forwarding constructors

Tags: javascript, typescript, strong-typing

I have a global variable `Module` that contains a bunch of constructors for javascript objects. In Javascript I can currently use them like this:

```
var obj1 = new Module.Class1(1,2,3);
var ob2 = new Module.Class2(»test«)
obj1.method1();
obj2.method2();
```

I would like to expose those in another namespace `NewNamespace`, and have strongly typed declarations for methods as well as for constructors. Something like this:

```
interface  Class1
{
  method1();
}

interface Class2
{
  method2();
}


// TODO: how to define constructors for NewNamespace

let obj2 : Class1= new NewNamespace.Class1(1,2,3);
let obj2 : Class2= new NewNamespace.Class1(1,2,3);
obj1.method1();
obj2.method2();
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You could add a `.d.ts` file to declare type information for your JavaScript classes instead of trying to "wrap" them with Typescript. This is how many JavaScript libraries work when used in Typescript.

Comment: The question is how to describe Module object which has a different function that can be used with `new` and returns different types. I guess, that using `constructor` would mean, that all those function would return class `Module`.